# How to read a text file line by line into an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, file

I am new to C, so this might be a foolish question, but I have a text file called dictionary.txt where each line is one word, and I want to read it word by word into an array so that each array index is a word, e.g array[0] will be the first word, array[1] will be the second etc. What is the best way to do this?

I've got this code that reads and outputs the file line by line, but I do not know how to store it into an array in the way that I've described.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
      if (argc != 2) {
            return -1;
      }

      char * line = NULL;
      size_t len = 0;
      ssize_t read;
      FILE * f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

      if (f == NULL) {
            return 0;
      }

      while ((read = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
            printf("%s", line);
      }

      fclose(f);
}
```